# jquery autocomplete on copy paste not trigger change event - ie11

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

Copy paste not working in ie11-
I am trying to set value of autocomplete by using ctrl+v, then after instantally i fired another shortcut button click(F8) event.
But problem is that whenever I doing above behaviour the button command event fired first instead of autocomplete change. Then value is not updated into autocomplete observable.

**This is working on all other browser just Internet Explorer causes issue.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery Autocomplete change is fired only when the control loose focus or after the specified delay. If you want to fire the change immediately you can have set delay to 0 millisecond or force the blur event of the contorl.